# Terminated input by end of file

Tags: c

I have asked to out the difference between two integers.

But I got

> input is terminated by "End of file".

I don't understand this. Here they also say one number is always large.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int h,o,sum,temp;
    scanf("%d %d",&h,&o);
    if (h > o)
    {
        temp = h ;
        h = o;
        o = temp;
    }

    sum = o - h;
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What do you type in when you run this?

Comment: aside: don't call `sum` a variable that stores the result of a subtraction, maybe `sub`?

Comment: @Vaibhav "end of file" != "end of line"